# Building pre-release apk of expo managed app failed

Tags: expo

Development environment:

- react: 18.2.0
- react-native: 0.71.8
- expo SDK : 48.0.18
- project: expo managed
- OS: windows

**What I expected**

App is currently working as expected with "npx expo start". I wanted to build an apk for the app so that I can get the apk install or share a link that expo will generate so that I can share it with collaborators/partners inorder to view the development process as I work on the app.

I was trying to build an apk and share an expo pre-release build of my app by using the "eas build -p android --profile preview" but the build was never successful. Expo doesn't handle the android and ios directory for build which eliminates the part of editing or modifying gradle settings in expo managed project. The build error has to do with "Deprecated Gradle" for react-native-reacnimated and I fix that by upgrading my gradle to version 8.3 and I got that fixed as the error wasn't showing again; another error occurred again back to incompatibility between Gradle and Kotlin. I got frustrated and deleted the android folder to remove the gradle settings I have modified since I read everywhere that expo handles build settings.

After exploring the internet, I found a package called react-native-gradle-plugin(https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36642) that claims to managed the Gradle setting for react native build and I followed the steps but still got an error. At the react-native-gradle-plugin(https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36642) url, the steps mentioned that we should edit "bundle.gradle" and "settings.gradle" file and I created a folder called "android" manually and created the two files with the contents as instructed on the url and with this i got react-native-reanimated error that I first resolved by upgrading gradle to 8.3.

I have been facing this issue for over XMRbuild done since expo manages the build automatically but the build could not complete because of some android setting that expo is meant to handle?

Thank you